# What's the default compression algorithm used by Windows's Compression tool?

Tags: windows-10, compression, zip, default-settings

I'm trying to find out some documentation which details out which compression algorithm (e.g. deflate, LZMA, BZip2) is used by Windows 10's Send to 'Compressed Folder' tool.

Some people reported that they could not open the 6GB zip files I had sent them, even though I could open it on a different windows machine.

Comment: There is a related question in Reverse Engineering : http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/are-there-any-tools-or-scripts-for-identifying-compression-algorithms-in-executa. Tools recommended here might offer some help on your problem too. I can't try on my own at the moment because of OS difference.

Comment: Open the archive with 7-zip, the 'details' view has a column showing the compression method used for each file.